# Prove that $f^{-1}\mathbb{R}^+f\subsetneqq Aut(\mathbb{I})$!

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, lattice-orders, ordered-fields

Let $\mathbb{I}=([0,1],\leq)$ and suppose

$Aut(\mathbb{I})=\{f|f:\mathbb{I}\longrightarrow \mathbb{I}, \text{$f$ is 1-1 and onto and $x\leq$ y iff $f(x)\leq f(y)$}\}$.

For any $f\in Aut(\mathbb{I})$ and $r\in \mathbb{R}^+$, define $rf$ by $(rf)(x)=f(x)^r$. I am trying to show that
$f^{-1}\mathbb{R}^+f\subsetneqq Aut(\mathbb{I})$ where $f^{-1}\mathbb{R}^+f=\{f^{-1}rf|r\in \mathbb{R}^+\}$ and $(f^{-1}rf)(x)=f^{-1}(f(x)^r)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Of course it is obvious that $f^{-1}\mathbb{R}^+f\subseteq Aut(\mathbb{I})$. But why $f^{-1}\mathbb{R}^+f\neq Aut(\mathbb{I})$? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using $\mathbb{R}^+ = (0,+\infty)$?

Comment: You seem to be testing whether this statement is true for a fixed $f$. It clearly is false in the case that $f=\operatorname{Id}_{\mathbb I}$ because then you would be asserting that every automorphism is of the form $x\mapsto x^r$.

Comment: @GaryMoon Yes...

Comment: @MPW $f$ is fix but arbitrary, not necessarily identity.

Comment: Yes, but it fails in that case, so it can't be true for *every* $f$. Which $f$ are you considering?

Comment: If $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are differentiable, then it will also fail. This is because the composition will also be differentiable on the interior but there are plenty of automorphisms which are piecewise linear but not differentiable at transitions between pieces.

Comment: My initial thought was that $f^{-1}\mathbb{R}^+f$ may exclude $\mathrm{id} \in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{I})$.

Comment: @GaryMoon : Won't you recover $\operatorname{id}$ for any $f$ when $r=1$?

Comment: @MPW Of course you would. For whatever reason I was thinking about $r\in (0,1)$ (even after clarifying the issue). Seems I've had a bit of a brain lapse. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider $r>0$ as the isomorphism $x\mapsto x^r$, so $rf$ and $f^{-1}rf$ are just compositions. So $\mathbb R^+$ is a (proper) subgroup of $Aut(\mathbb I)$, and $f^{-1}\mathbb R^+f$ are its conjugates, hence also proper subgroups.